# how to load xml into memory in faster way?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing

I am new to objective-c. I load the whole xml string from server to an nsxml parser like below: but the problem is loding from url to memory takes much more time than parsing it. how can i solve that? (my app is very slow)

```
xmlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:&NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSData *xmlData = [xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
```

Comment: Tunnel the data ... well, seriously, you can hardly improve the speed of the network connection, hence you will learn to live with it. You might want to move the loading part away from the UI thread to keep the app responsive, that is it.

Comment: @Till You might want to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your XML Parser in different Thread.(this will not make your parsing faster)
[How To Choose The Best XML Parser for Your iPhone Project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)

Comment: Suppose you have function -(void)xmlParser: (NSData *)Parameter; then call this function 
[self performSelector:@selector(xmlParser:) withObject:ParameterObject afterDelay:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>]; this will create  new thread for Parsing. this will not block your main thread

Comment: For passing more then one argument to thread , use NSDictionary object.

Comment: @Parag And a thread will make the parsing faster how? The question is not how to achieve better concurrency.

Comment: @CocoaFu No, this will not make the parsing faster. but i think Finutv is not using different thread for parsing.

Comment: @Parag actually i dont use threads for parsing. so in threading i can divided my xml into many thread?

Comment: @Finutv Not easily (I have done it) and it will take the same or slightly more cpu time. If there is more than one core the clock time can be reduced. In my case I was reducing temp memory usage, not time.

Answer (score 0):

Basically NSXMLParser is slow. There is a possibility of finding a better parser for the specific need. A true stream parser might help if you do not need the entire DOM and validation.

Comment: In my case libxml2 would help but i am wondering i am allowed to use third party class in app store?

Comment: Yes you can as long as it is compiled into the app.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
 xmlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:&NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Use a network library like [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to load the content from a URL and then parse it.

Loading directly from URL like you've done will hang your app till the data is loaded.

Download and install that library as given in the instructions (it's easy), then you can do

```
{
   //in some function
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request startAsynchronous]; //this will load URL in background
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   // Use when fetching text data
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

   //parse the XML here
   [self parseXML:responseString];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSError *error = [request error];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load the xml faster from the url as it totally depends on your internet connection.

To keep your application smooth, you need to parse the xml in another thread. I answered a similar question in the following url

[How to handle freezing programm at loading xml from bad url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209583/how-to-handle-freezing-programm-at-loading-xml-from-bad-url/8210089#8210089)

Also there are faster XML parser than the defaul NSXMLParser. There is a good introduction about them in the following blog post. So you can use any of these parser in place of NSXMLParser to improve the performance of your application.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

I hope that it may clarify a little bit of your question.